# Linq and Connection Pools

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I an having connection pool issues (reaching maximium pool size). The application uses Linq2SQL in most cases with some legacy function still using SqlConnection

All my Link2SQL sections have these common sections:

```
Dim dc As New dbDataContext

... some Linq code

dc.Connection.Close()
dc.Dispose()
```

Have I done enough to ensure my sql connection have been closed and all necessary resources disposed?

Comment: Can using the same connection string param stored in web.config for both Linq2Sql and SqlConnection cause issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted my problem. I have defined two connections strings in my web.config One is used by the datacontext and the other by the legacy sqlConnection code. This seems to have eliminated the pooled connection time-out issue... although I have no idea why.